# Jquery template is breaking script

Tags: javascript

I found a script which I want to use to my website. The problem is that this script is using jquery.tmpl which is messing some stuff on my site.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cameras/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>
```

I think it may be any conflict there with jQuery which I am using for some menus.

```
 <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

Is there anything I can do to fix that ?

Regards,

Comment: did you have an example with both scripts working? try to add them in same order and in same html zone to avoid problems....

Comment: You can use no conflict: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Answer (score 0):

use noConflict();

```
    <script src="other_lib.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $.noConflict();
    jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
      // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
    });
    // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
    </script>
```